# Changes of the Y value of plt.text position doesn't affect to text position

Tags: pandas, matplotlib

See also updates below.

By using `plt.text` to annotate my chart I would place it below the figure:

```python
plt.text(x=0, y=5,
         s='Джерело: openbudget.gov.ua', ha='left', fontsize=9, alpha=0.7,)
```

[image]

When I change the `x` position value, it works correctly, but changes to `y` value does not affect to text position at all -- space between bottom edge of the chat and annotation text (arrow) doesn't change.

The question is -- why changes of the `y` text position value does not affect to actual text position in case of given chart (I had annotate charts this way before and it had worked fine)?

**Dataframe source data:**

```
{"year":{"0":2021,"1":2021,"2":2021,"3":2021,"4":2021,"5":2021,"6":2021,"7":2021,"8":2021,"9":2021,"10":2021,"11":2021,"12":2022,"13":2022,"14":2022,"15":2022},"month":{"0":1,"1":2,"2":3,"3":4,"4":5,"5":6,"6":7,"7":8,"8":9,"9":10,"10":11,"11":12,"12":1,"13":2,"14":3,"15":4},"zn":{"0":8403533.0,"1":13708653.3,"2":12754794.0,"3":13003063.2,"4":13799415.0,"5":24882118.4,"6":7330157.5,"7":7360882.7,"8":13355428.8,"9":12990686.3,"10":13236689.3,"11":17756139.6,"12":11600703.4,"13":13643288.9,"14":12591057.9,"15":11387693.1},"mon":{"0":"січ","1":"лют","2":"бер","3":"кві","4":"тра","5":"чер","6":"лип","7":"сер","8":"вер","9":"жов","10":"лис","11":"гру","12":"січ","13":"лют","14":"бер","15":"кві"}}
```

**Chart code source**

```python
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
import seaborn as sns
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

plt.style.use('seaborn')
palette = {2021: '#55A868', 2022: '#8172B2'}

fontdict = {'size': 13,}

fig, ax = plt.subplots(nrows=1, ncols=1)
ax = sns.lineplot(
    x='mon', y='zn',
    data=data,
    hue=data['year'], palette=palette,
    ci=None, linewidth=3)
ax.legend().set_title("Рік", prop=fontdict)
yk = np.array([x/1000000 for x in list(ax.get_yticks())])
ax.set_yticks(ax.get_yticks())
ax.set_yticklabels(labels=yk)
ax.set_ylabel('млрд. грн.', fontdict={'size': 11})
ax.set_xlabel(None)
ax.set_title('Витрати місцевих бюджетів на оплату праці\n'
             "(дошкільна, загальна середня освіта, бюджети міст, сіл, селищ)",
             fontdict={'size': 15,}
            )
plt.text(x=0, 
         y=60, # changes to this parameter has no effect
         s='Джерело: openbudget.gov.ua', ha='left', fontsize=9, alpha=0.7,)
plt.show()
```

###### Update 1

@Redox noticed me in the comment, that described behaviour cannot be reproduced and position of the text changes accordingly to changes of Y value.

In turn I try to run my code within clear VM with Ipython and found that desired text annotation would not appear at all -- I got chart only, without any annotation.

My libraries versions is:

```
matplotlib==3.5.2
matplotlib-inline==0.1.3
pandas==1.4.2
seaborn==0.11.2
```

Comment: The code (except for data which is not available above) runs ok. I am able to move it up and down correctly by changing `y`. The issue might be somewhere else

Comment: @Redox Just tried run my code inside venv, and annotation text doesn't appear at all. However, I'll add new information to question, thank you. P. S. I provide chart data as dict, maybe u miss it?

Comment: Coordinate axes include data basis, axis basis, and figure basis. See here for [more information](https://matplotlib.org/stable/tutorials/advanced/transforms_tutorial.html). If the desired placement is just below the scale, try the following code. `ax.text(x=0,y=-0.1,transform=ax.transAxes,s='Джерело: openbudget.gov.ua',ha='left',fontsize=9,alpha=0.7)
`

Comment: @r-beginners It works, thank you! Can you add your explanation as an answer?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Adding a string as an annotation can be specified flexibly by using the coordinate system of the graph. Types include data, axis, and graph area. See here for more [details](https://matplotlib.org/stable/tutorials/advanced/transforms_tutorial.html).

```
plt.text(x=0, 
         y=60, # changes to this parameter has no effect
         s='Джерело: openbudget.gov.ua', ha='left', fontsize=9, alpha=0.7,)
```

If the coordinates are specified in axes:.

```
plt.text(x=0, y=-0.1, transform=ax.transAxes, s='Джерело: openbudget.gov.ua', ha='left', fontsize=9, alpha=0.7,)
```

[image]